# Difficulty finding underlying startup errors: Is there another log file?

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss

I've been attempting to deploy a single WAR file any number of ways on **JBoss 6.1.0.final** with no success, while the only error messages I can find are of no use (unless I'm missing something...).

Now - I think it's fair to say that I'm expecting errors since I am the first person to attempt to deploy our web application on JBoss. Currently it runs happily in Tomcat and JOnAS.

My IDE of choice is IntelliJ - I have posted a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759407/running-jboss-6-locally-from-intellij-8-jndi-port-configuration-not-found) since IntelliJ has issues deploying locally. Instead I have been attempting to deploy using a remote run configuration. However, this is by no means the only way I have tried to get JBoss to give me an error message that is even remotely helpful!

---

*Firstly here are my JBoss configuration files that reside in WEB-INF directory* (N.B. I am new to JBoss but have been advised to use these, I would expect errors nonetheless, but any JBoss errors as a result, I would hope, would clearly be related to a specific file):

**jboss-scanning.xml**

```
<scanning xmlns="urn:jboss:scanning:1.0">
<!-- Purpose:  Disable scanning for annotations in contained deployment. -->
</scanning>
```

**jboss-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<structure>
    <context>
        <path name=""/>
        <metaDataPath>
            <path name="META-INF"/>
        </metaDataPath>
        <classpath>
            <path name=""/>
            <path name="" suffixes=".jar" />
            <path name="lib" suffixes=".jar" />
        </classpath>
    </context>
</structure>
```

**jboss-classloading.xml**

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
              name="EM.war"
              domain="EM.war"

              parent-domain="DefaultDomain"

              export-all="NON_EMPTY"
              import-all="true">
</classloading>
```

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE jboss-web
    PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 2.3V2//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_3_2.dtd">

<jboss-web>

  <!-- A security domain that restricts access -->
  <security-domain>java:/jaas/em</security-domain>

  <context-root>EM</context-root>

</jboss-web>
```

*I have been looking in the following log files (as well as console windows) for more detailed errors:*

- C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\default\log\boot.log
- C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\default\log\server.log
- My web application's log directory but nothing is printed since clearly it's not getting far enough

Are there any more files anywhere?

---

*The following are attempts made and the errors printed in various consoles / log files:*

**IntelliJ (8.1) deploying my EM.war as an exploded directory:**

```
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy: file:/D:/pro/out/EM.war/
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670)
    at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1426)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1264)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1359)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:788)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

vfs:///D:/pro/out/EM.war -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/pro/out/EM.war/ deployment failed


DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///D:/pro/out/EM.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/pro/out/EM.war/ deployment failed

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1370)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1316)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:968)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:957)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:383)
    ... 29 more
```

The same errors occur when deploying through IntelliJ as a WARred up file.

**Deploying an EM.war (WARred up file, i.e. not exploded) through JBoss' web console:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:38)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:86)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:58)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
at org.jboss.on.embedded.LazyStartupFilter.doFilter(LazyStartupFilter.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by:javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:38)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:86)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:58)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
at org.jboss.on.embedded.LazyStartupFilter.doFilter(LazyStartupFilter.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:31)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
at org.jboss.seam.core.ConversationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(ConversationInterceptor.java:56)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:166)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:102)
at org.jboss.on.embedded.ui.content.CreateContentBackedResourceAction_$$_javassist_14.createContentBackedResource(CreateContentBackedResourceAction_$$_javassist_14.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:329)
at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:274)
at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.invoke(AstMethodSuffix.java:65)
at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:38)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:86)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:58)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
at org.jboss.on.embedded.LazyStartupFilter.doFilter(LazyStartupFilter.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

**Dropping the exploded EM.war directory into C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\default\deploy:**

```
...
17:48:23,167 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'JBossQuartzScheduler' initialized from an externally opened InputStream.
17:48:23,167 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.8.3
17:48:23,167 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler JBossQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
17:48:23,604 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS'
17:48:23,823 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'
17:48:23,901 INFO  [xnio] XNIO Version 2.1.0.CR2
17:48:23,901 INFO  [nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 2.1.0.CR2
17:48:24,042 INFO  [remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.1.0.Beta2
17:48:24,120 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/
17:48:24,167 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/EM
17:48:34,870 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile:: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///C:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/EM.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/EM.war/ deployment failed

        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1228) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:905) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:87) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.checkAllComplete(ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.java:107) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:135) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_10]

17:48:34,886 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
17:48:34,901 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
17:48:34,901 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer] JBossAS [6.1.0.Final "Neo"] Started in 1m:172ms
```

There are no 'previous errors' that I can find :(

And finally, having made the assumption some of my JBoss config were incorrect-

**Startup from IntelliJ *without* my jboss-scanning.xml or jboss-structure.xml files:**

```
Connected to server
[2012-01-09 05:25:18,744] Facet Web: Facet is being deployed, please wait...
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy: file:/D:/pro/out/EM.war/
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670)
    at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1426)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1264)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1359)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:788)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

vfs:///pro/out/EM.war -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///D:/pro/out/EM.war


DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///D:/pro/out/EM.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1.0.com.sun.codemodel.JBreak

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1370)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1316)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:968)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:957)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:383)
    ... 29 more
[2012-01-09 05:27:06,947] Facet Web: Error during facet deployment. See server log for details.
```

Is this worth investigating? At least I now have a ClassNotFoundException to go on...

---

Any ideas / suggestions welcome!

Thanks in advance, and apologies for the length of the question!